# Перехват запросов посредством "JS" в расширении браузера "Chrome"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, request

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, а в идеале привести примеры реализации данного задания: "Перехватить запрос, сделать ему cancel, а потом его урл и хидеры вывести на страницы в таком виде
You have requested ${url} URL
With the next headers: ${listOfHeaders}
". Всё создаётся посредством "JS" в виде расширения под "Chrome".

Comment: Может тут? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684024/how-to-cancel-webrequest-silently-in-chrome-extension

Comment: Часть здесь можно взять, но как потом урл и хидеры вывести на страницу в таком виде
You have requested ${url} URL
With the next headers: ${listOfHeaders}?